# Double execution (2 threads) of Spring cron job in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Java + Spring (3.2.9.RELEASE) stack deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk configured with max of 1 instance. However, I am noticing my background job is being executed twice in a row in that instance in 2 different threads.

The background job is scheduled as cron jobs, Spring set up:

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="scheduler" />
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="5" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">

    <task:scheduled ref="className1" method="methodName1"
        cron="${scheduler.property1name.cronschedule}" />

    <task:scheduled ref="className2" method="methodName2"
        cron="${scheduler.property2name.cronschedule}" />

    <task:scheduled ref="className3" method="methodName3"
        cron="${scheduler.property3name.cronschedule}" />

</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

For application logic reasons, methodName1 is the only one that actually execute tasks (methodName2 and other tasks does not meet application logic condition). Since I am noticing methodName1 being executed twice, I added logging to see where it's coming from:

```
public void methodName1()
{
    // DEBUGGING to see which machine is running in AWS
    try
    {
        java.net.InetAddress localMachine = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        logger.debug("Hostname of local machine: " + localMachine.getHostName() + "/ " + localMachine.getHostAddress());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logger.debug("Failed to retrieve machine name", ex);
    }
    // DEBUGGING

    actuallyExecuteMethodName1();
}
```

Now, this very same code has been running in our own internal server (single node set up) for the past year with no issue. Recently, we moved this application into AWS and more specifically to Elastic Beanstalk. We know we have not configured the background job to handle multi-node environnment, and thus we set up Elastic Beanstalk to have min/max of 1 instance until we make the necessary changes.

Looking at the application log from AWS:

```
04:15:00,002 [scheduler-3] DEBUG ClassName1- methodName1- Hostname of local machine: ip-###.###.###.###/ ###.###.###.###
04:15:00,003 [scheduler-2] DEBUG ClassName1- methodName1- Hostname of local machine: ip-###.###.###.###/ ###.###.###.###
```

The task is executed twice, each on a different thread 1 milliseconds apart.
We are only seeing this behavior after we moved to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The app is running on:
64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.2 running Tomcat 7 Java 7

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you give the exact name of the Tomcat solution stack you are using?

Comment: 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.2 running Tomcat 7 Java 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the latest solution stack "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Tomcat 7 Java 7" for your environment.

Comment: Any reason why upgrading the Amazon Linux image version would help me? Was there any particular bug that was fixed?

Comment: Several bug fixes happened between that release and this one. I cannot point to one bug fix to explain the behavior you are seeing. May be with detailed logs from the instance I can dig deeper, but I would recommend using the latest version and hopefully you won't see a problem with the latest one. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Rohit - so you are thinking it's completely plausible that the multiple execution on different thread is caused by the container rather than on the application level? Do you have release notes / change log between 1.0.2 and 1.0.4? Thank you!

Comment: I am not a 100% certain that it is a container issue.

Comment: That's fine, thanks ... do you have release notes / change logs on those version updates? I need something that I can dig around to explain this behaviour

Comment: I could not find detailed release notes in the public beanstalk documentation for this particular solution stack. The 2014.03 comes with a newer version of OS and there is support for t2.micro instances. That information is available in docs but that alone would not explain the behavior you are seeing. Detailed logs from instance can  help explain the behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60936/discussion-between-rohit-banga-and-ts).